# Is there a name for this type of construction? E.g. a scorcher of a day; a geyser of a character, etc

Tags: grammar, construction

I've seem a lot of such constructions, e.g. a spasm of a rant. What do grammarians call such constructions, and is there anything in particular that an EFL teacher needs to know about them, to teach them to their students?

Thank you very much for taking your time to answer my question. Have a good day!

Comment: Implied comparisons are metaphors.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just wondering - isn't an implied comparison something like: Samuel brayed his refusal to leave the party peacefully. (Compares Samuel to a donkey)? examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-implied-metaphor.html Thanks!

Comment: Good example there.